# SQL optional parameter?

Tags: mysql, sql

Lets say I have two tables:

Table1

```
Id Name
1 Joe
2 Greg
3 Susan
4 Max
```

Table2

```
Uid comment
2    Good customer
4    Great guy
```

What I want to do is list all elements of Table 1, and if Table1.Id = Table2.Uid I want to select this comment. If comment does not exist give blank field.

Result should be:

```
1 Joe 
2 Greg Good customer
3 Susan
4 Max Great Guy
```

I can't figure out how to do it, if I write:

```
select
table1.Id,
table1.Name,
table2.comment

where
table1.id=table2.Uid
```

It gives me only users 2 and 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use `left join` it shows you all data from `table1`

```
select t1.Id, t1.Name, t2.comment
from table1 t1
left join table2 t2 on t1.id=t2.Uid
```

**NOTE**:

Good practice is to use aliases as above. Code is more readable.

Answer (score 1):

```
select
table1.Id,
table1.Name,
table2.comment
from table1 left outer join table2 on table1.id=table2.Uid
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a classical `JOIN` operation:

```
SELECT 
        t1.id, t1.name, t2.comment 
FROM 
       Table1 AS t1 
LEFT JOIN 
       Table2 AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.uid
```

Comment: @Parado yes I am sure, why?

Comment: join is equivalent of `table1.id=table2.Uid` as OP's question (not my downvote)

Comment: The downvote was mine because this answer was wrong: it did not achieve what the OP asked

Comment: I have already given you +1 @Parado. You are the man. OK? Happy? What can I do? Do you want me to delete my answer?

Comment: You can leave it, I don't care